# Where did the work done by smaller force go?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, work, spring

Suppose I have a spring of spring constant 150 N/m.One person pulls with it a force of 15 N. The extension produced is 0.1 m. Now another person comes and pulls with a force of 30 N (The first person is still there). The final extension is 0.3 m.The initial and final potential energies of the spring are 0.75 J and 6.75 J respectively. The work done by the bigger force is 6 J which is exactly equal to the change in P.E of the spring. So where did the work done by the smaller force (when they were pulling it together) go? Why didn't it help to further increase the potential energy of the spring?

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand your question, but you said, the bigger force is equal to the change in P.E. of a spring. Work done by the smaller force increases spring energy to 0.75J, bigger 'extends' it to 6.75 from your assumptions. So work done by a lesser force increased potential of our spring to 0.75J Thus that's where it 'goes'

Comment: Have you considered the discrepancy that for the first person $\frac12kx^2\neq Fx$? You can't get the spring to come to rest if you just apply a constant force. Think of a mass hanging on a spring

Comment: Yesi have considered

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The work done by the bigger force is 6J which is exactly equal to the change in P.E of the spring.

Actually, this is incorrect. If we don't want to be adding kinetic energy and worrying about that, then the total force from the people must at all times equal the force from the spring. This means that the force from the second person is only 30 N at full extension and is less than 30 N before then. Here is a plot of the forces vs displacement. The blue line is the total force from both people, the yellow line is the force from the first person, and the green line is the force from the second person.

[image: Force vs displacement]

In this plot the work is the area under the curve. It is immediately obvious that the area under the blue curve is the sum of the areas under the curve for the yellow and for the green person.

What is not so obvious is that the work done by the first person is actually more than the work done by the second. The area under the green curve is 3.0 J, not 6.0 J. The area under the yellow curve is 3.75 J, with 0.75 J under the initial triangular portion from 0 to 0.1 m and the remaining 3.0 J in the flat section.

So, indeed, the work done by the smaller force is essential for calculating the total energy that went into the spring. The calculation of 6.0 J from the second person is simply incorrect. It is incorrect by a factor of 2 which basically is the difference between incorrectly assuming that the 30 N force was applied throughout the movement instead of correctly recognizing that it is only 30 N at full extension. Of course, alternatively you could consider the change in KE that would result from a constant 30 N force, as described by @Aaron Stevens in his answer.

Comment: Nice work, Dale. I have edit my answer to include a link to your answer, as it covers one of the options I mentioned :)

Comment: For your final paragraph, the issue isn't that constant applied force is assumed. The issue is that this was assumed *and* it was assumed that doing this you would stop the spring when $x=F_\text{app}/k$. Both cannot be assumed at the same time, but either one by itself is fine with modification to the other.

Comment: @AaronStevens good point. I will update my final paragraph

Comment: I see your force graph, and raise you a work graph ;)

Comment: Looks like you win

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to compare the work done by constant forces to the change in potential energy of the spring. However, if you take a spring at rest at its current equilibrium and then apply a purely constant force to it, then the spring will not come to rest at a new equilibrium position; it will start oscillating about that new equilibrium instead. This is why, for example, with your first person $\frac12kx^2\neq Fx$ where $x$ is the distance between the old and new equilibrium positions. The constant force does more work getting to the new equilibrium position than the spring does. Therefore, we will still have motion, as the extra energy will have gone into kinetic energy.

Therefore, you need to change either your assumptions or your analysis here. Either make the applied forces variable so that you can stop the spring at any equilibrium as done in [Dale's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/546127/179151), or keep the applied forces constant and then either correctly include kinetic energy, or look at the points where the spring would actually momentarily come to rest (so then you can equate $\frac12kx^2$ and $Fx$).

---

I will go ahead and provide the other option, choosing the scenario where we apply constant forces, and the spring comes to rest so that we do not need to consider kinetic energy. For a constant applied force $F$, the spring will come to rest when the work done by the spring is equal to the work done by the force, so that the stopping position is $x=2F/k$. Therefore, when the $15\,\mathrm N$ force is applied, the spring will momentarily stop at $x_1=0.2\,\mathrm m$. You can do a similar argument to show that once we then start the $30\,\mathrm N$ force we will get another momentary stopping at $x_2=0.4\,\mathrm m$.

Following Dale's graphs, we have for the forces

[image]

and for the work done by each force

[image]

As you can see, once the spring momentarily comes to rest at $0.4\,\mathrm m$, the total $12\,\mathrm J$ of work done by the applied forces is equal in magnitude to the work done by the spring. Additionally, each force does $6\,\mathrm J$ of work, so the work done by both people are accounted for in the total work.

Comment: Excellent work graph. +1! This has to be one of the best answered questions of its kind ever.

Comment: @Dale Your answer gave the motivation to fully consider the other option. Let's propose the ability to combine answers on meta :P

Answer (score 1):

When both are pulling it together, the total fore is $45\ \mathrm N$ and the extension is $0.3\ \mathrm m$ and the work-done is still $6.75\ \mathrm J$. When they pull individually the work done is $6\ \mathrm J$ and $0.75\ \mathrm J$ respectively irrespective of who pulls first. It doesn't matter how they are being pulled; together or individually, the contribution remains the same.

Comment: You probably didn't understand my question. The spring is already extended by 0.1 m by the smaller force.Then the bigger force comes and they together make it 0.3m. so the work done by bigger one is 0.2*30=6J and the work done by the smaller force(when they together pull the spring)is 0.2*15=3J. Now if you see carefully only the work done by the bigger force has gone into the extra P.E.(6J) gained by the spring. Where did the work done by smaller force go?

Comment: When they pull together the $0.2$ meters their combined work is the $6$ Joules. It's not like the first person isn't doing work after the second person starts pulling.

Comment: But if we see the combined work,it is nothing but 45*0.2=9J. How can it be so? The work we are getting is more than the P.E gained by the spring.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “pulling individually”?

Comment: See it like this..Both the guys have attached their own threads to the end of the spring and are pulling it

Comment: I think you got the wrong formula for work done. It's not simply $F.x$. It's actually $\int{F.dx}$. Or you can just apply work-energy theorem.
Work here is given by $$W=\frac{1}{2}k(x_i^2-x_f^2)$$

Comment: where F is $kx$ and not the external force. When you apply a force to a massless spring, it doesn't get in equilibrium instantly. There is a motion involve and the net acceleration on the mass, m attached to it at any extension is given by $\frac{F_{ext}-kx}{m}$

Comment: Vikash is correct. Force is not constant over the displacement $x$

Comment: @BobD The OP is assuming the the applied forces are constant though. Hence the issues